# Get specific level of directory

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

i would like to get the original folder name by dynamic path and username, and without Windows default directory

For example,

```
 C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\2014-11-03\Spreadsheets\excel.xls
 C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\record.xls
```

In this case, i want it to return "History" for excel.xls & record.xls. I tried to use GetFilename() method. But it just returns

```
 Spreadsheets - excel.xls
 History      - record.xls
```

Is it possible to achieve? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as [documented of `Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Returns the **file name and extension** of the specified path string.

One solution can be delete your `Desktop` path and split with [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) character and gets second element.

For example;

```
string path = @"C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\2014-11-03\Spreadsheets\excel.xls";
var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

path = path.Replace(desktop, "");
var history = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)[1];
Console.WriteLine(history); // History
```

Remember, [`Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns current user desktop information.

Comment: this assumes that the paths start from the desktop and contained within a single folder.

Comment: @cjb110 No, it doesn't. Have you _ever_ look at my example? It has `\History\2014-11-03` which means this string two inner folders except `Desktop` path. Even if there was more than two folders, my solution will work because it get's second element after the split (first one is empty string because `path` starts with `\ character`) operation and in OP's case, it always will be `History`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built way of doing what you want. The following code should do the trick:

```
    public static string GetFolderByLevel(this string path, string baseFolderName, int level)
    {
        if (path == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

        if (baseFolderName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("baseFolderName");

        var pathWithoutFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        var folders = pathWithoutFile.ToString().Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        int baseFolderLevel = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < folders.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (string.Compare(folders[i], baseFolderName, true) == 0)
            {
                baseFolderLevel = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (baseFolderLevel == -1)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Folder '{0}' could not be found in specified path: {1}", baseFolderName, path), "baseFolderName");

        int index = baseFolderLevel + level;

        if (-1 < index && index < folders.Length)
        {
            return folders[index];
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Specified level is out of range."));
    }
```

Now you can use it like:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\Peter\record.xls";

path.GetFolderByLevel("Desktop", -2); //returns "Users"
path.GetFolderByLevel("History", 0); //returns "History"
path.GetFolderByLevel("Desktop", 1); //returns "History"
```

In your case, if I'm not mistaken, your are looking for `path.GetFolderByLevel("Desktop", 1);`

***UPDATE***: I've modified the previous solution so that you can specify the *base folder* with a partial or full path:

```
public static string GetFolderByLevel(this string path, string baseFolderPath, int level)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

    if (baseFolderPath == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("baseFolderName");

    var pathFolders = path.Split(new char[] {Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var basePathFolders = baseFolderPath.Split(new char[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    int baseFolderIndex = -1;
    int folderCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pathFolders.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (string.Compare(pathFolders[i], basePathFolders[folderCounter], true) == 0)
        {
            if (++folderCounter == basePathFolders.Length)
            {
                baseFolderIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            folderCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    if (baseFolderIndex < 0)
       throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Folder '{0}' could not be found in specified path: {1}", baseFolderPath, path), "baseFolderName");

    int index = baseFolderIndex + level;

    if (-1 < index && index < pathFolders.Length)
    {
        return pathFolders[index];
    }
    else
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Specified level is out of range."));
}
```

Now you could use it like: `path.GetFolderByLevel(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), 1);`

An additional advantage would be in case of having nested folders with the same name, you can specify the unique partial path of the base folder to make sure the method picks the right one.

Comment: clever, but I don't think the OP will know the number of levels he needs.

Comment: @cjb110 yes he does, one level over desktop unless I've misunderstood the OP's question.

Comment: ah, you went up the paths:) I went down, thinking he's got an unknown set of paths and wants to find the common base path.

Comment: exactly, the number of levels is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

So if I've understood you want to find the common base path from a set of paths?
There isn't any built in function to do this, so your back to string matching and some LINQ gives this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> paths = new List<string>()
            {
                @"C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\2014-11-03\Spreadsheets\excel.xls"
                ,@"C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\record.xls"
                ,@"C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\2014-11-23\Spreadsheets\excel.xls"
                ,@"C:\Users\dynamic user\Desktop\History\2014-11-03\excel.xls"
            };

        Console.WriteLine("The common base path of:");
        paths.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
        Console.WriteLine("is");
        Console.WriteLine(FindBasePath(paths));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string FindBasePath(List<string> paths)
    {
        string basePath = String.Empty;

        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

            if (paths.All(f => Path.GetDirectoryName(f).Contains(dirName)))
                return basePath = dirName;
        }

        return basePath;
    }
```

Forgot to add comment as to what we're doing.  Basically we loop over every path, and get the name of the directory, then if *ALL* the paths contains this string, it must be the common root directory.

Note this will check every path against every other path...and could be improved.

You could also do it one LINQ statement:

```
paths.Select(f => Path.GetDirectoryName(f)
     .Select(f => paths.All(g => g.Contains(f)) ? f : "")
     .Where(f => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
     .First()
```

Answer (score -1):

Or this:

```
 var dir_path = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\your\path\with\file.ext");
 var dir_name = new DirectoryInfo(dir_path).Name;
```

Comment: No, for `\History\2014-11-03`, this returns `2014-11-03` part not `History`.